# Where can I get Nagios plugin for cpu/hdd monitoring?

Tags: debian, nagios, snmp, plugin

I have already installed `nagios-plugins-contrib`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nagios-plugins-contrib
```

However, there are no any cpu / hdd management plugin.

I am using a Debian VM just in case.

How can I get this plugin (if it exists of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`monitoring-plugins-basic`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/monitoring-plugins-basic) provide 2 plugins , the `check_disk` to check the disk usage and the `check_load` to check the cpu:

```
apt install monitoring-plugins-basic
```

see:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_disk --help
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load --help
```

[Disk Space Checks](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/disk-space-checks-770.html)

[Load Checks](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/load-checks-771.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can download them from the [Nagios Exchange website](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins).

Depending on what you what you want to monitor (Cisco, Linux, or whatever) use the appropriate plug-in. Download them and add them to your Nagios `plugins` directory to use them.